# W3Schools unable to replicate tryit editor

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I was testing some code on the tryit editor and was unable to replicate functionality when I save the code locally and was wondering it anyone had any ideas as to why this seems to happen.

The code snippet is

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.w3schools.com/dom/loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml");
for (j=0;j<xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book").length;j++ )
{
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[j].childNodes;
    y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[j].firstChild;
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        if (y.nodeType==1)  
        {
            //Process only element nodes (type 1)  
            document.write(y.nodeName + " : " +x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />");  
        }
        y=y.nextSibling;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here

Many thanks in advance

Edit: Thanks to all for the w3schools tip. I think I abuse the tryit more than I should stop doing so

Comment: same domain policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into the same origin policy here.

Try saving the XML-file locally and load it from there instead of the remote server of w3schools.

Comment: Hey Sirko - thanks. I think that was the trouble. I didn't realise, but I tried the your solution independently and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The `loadXMLDoc()` w3schools provides uses `XMLHttpRequest` behind the scenes, which is restricted the Same Origin Policy. (SOP)

The [SOP states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you can only make requests to resources on the same domain.

When you save the file locally, you're no longer on the w3schools domain and so can't access files on it.

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}​
```

Comment: I suppose a follow up question would be - is there a better way to parse XML. 

My objective is to convert it to BibTeX.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you should avoid using w3schools as your reference http://w3fools.com

Second, you can't do that as `loadXMLDoc` is using AJAX and you can't request document in different domain using AJAX (Unless you use JSONP, but that's another subject altogether)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy